# How to assain new margins to ImageView based on onTouch event

Tags: java, android, xml

So basicly Im learning some java and android programming in free time and wanted to write app that changes image position based on onTouch event but it crashes and I can't figure out why.

Java code:

```
package com.FF.HLW;

import android.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView irisJ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

ImageView irisJ = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Iris);

}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
String coords = "X: "+ event.getX()+ " Y: "+event.getY();
Toast.makeText(this, coords,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

//params1.setMargins(Math.round(event.getX()), Math.round(event.getY()) ,0 ,0);
//irisJ.setLayoutParams(params1);

}
return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
}
```

Xml only has single ViewImage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/Iris"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"

android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

App crashes when I remove // after Toast lines.
Whats wrong?

Comment: hey, please give the logcat crash message

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to get it to work by myself. Removed ImageView from ine when I pick irisJ id in onCreate and it works now.